# Pureness of Vector States

Tags: abstract-algebra, operator-theory, inner-products, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

How does one show that irreducibility is equivalent to a vector state being pure?

In what follows I will fill in the details of the question: Let $\mathcal{H}$ denote a Hilbert space and let $\mathfrak{A}$ be the set of all linear transformations defined on all of $\mathcal{H}$. The latter is just the set of bounded operators on $\mathcal{H}$.

**Definition.** A *vector state* $\omega: \mathfrak{A} \to \Bbb F$ is given by the expectation of $a \in \mathfrak{A}$ in a vector $\Omega \in \mathcal{H},$ $$\omega (a) = \langle \Omega, a \Omega \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}$$ where $\Omega$ is a unit vector.

We say that a vector state is pure if it has no non-trivial decomposition into a convex sum of other states. When is a vector state pure? It turns out that purity is linked to the following algebraic property, namely is the algebra $\pi(\mathfrak{A})$ irreducible? Irreducibility means that the only element in the algebra commuting with the whole algebra is a multiple of the identity.

I'm stuck with the proof that shows equivalence of the aforementioned algebraic property and purity of a vector state. Help along these lines would be greatly appreciated.

Furthermore, can I phrase irreducibility in terms of the algebra's commutant, i.e. the algebra is irreducible iff the commutant contains the identity element and scalar multiples of it?

Comment: Every vector is cyclic for an irreducible representation and the GNS construction is unique up to isomorphism

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $\pi(\mathfrak{A})$ is irreducible iff **there exists** a pure vector state $\omega$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, that is what I would like to show.

Comment: I thought I've given enough hints to get to the answer...

Comment: @Phoenix87 I suppose that I am a slow

Comment: To be clear, I preferred to give hints rather than a straight answer, that might not have been of any help.

Comment: @Phoenix87 understandable, I'll continue to reflect on the hint.

Comment: @sunspots: in your question you are mixing two things: that vector states are pure (they all are) and that a state is pure iff its gns is irreducible.